# Need to parse this data with Json.NET

Tags: c#, xamarin, json.net

Here is a string named responseString I get from server.
If I use Console.Write(responseString) I get the following output

```
{
    "success": true,
    "info": "Logged in :) ",
    "data": {
        "authentication_token": "iexGFwJ6HwERQZ3wJ4NG"
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need the value of the key "authentication_token".
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Great. Do so. If you have problems and you have a question, feel free to post your best try and a description what *exactly* you need help with.

Comment: create your POCO object to deserialize json into, call `var myPoco = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<POCOclass>(json_string_here);`.  `myPoco.authentication_token` hopefully have your token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this way:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(responseString);
Console.WriteLine(json["data"]["authentication_token"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that better way is to create two classess:

```
public class Data
 {
   public string authentication_token { get; set; }
 }

public class RootObject
 {
   public bool success { get; set; }
   public string info { get; set; }
   public Data data { get; set; }
 }
```

Now you will have access to authentication token in variable: authentication_token in Data class:

```
RootObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(*yourJSON*);
string token = myObject.data.authentication_token;
```